# How can I remove part of a string with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('.select-topic').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-list') == "N") {
        $(this).attr('data-list', 'Y')
        var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID').html();
        $(this).html(topicSelectHtml);
        $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'Y')
    }
```

When a user clicks on a new topic then it takes the `$('#TopicID').html();` and uses this as the html for `topicSelectHtml`.

This works but what I need to do is to remove a section of the `$('#TopicID').html();` that's not required for the new select. Here is my select html:

```
<select name="TopicID" id="TopicID"><optgroup label="Admin">
<option value="00">All Topics</option>
<option value="050002">Classes</option>
</optgroup>
xxxxxxxxx</select>
```

How can I remove the `<optgroup label="Admin"> ... </optgroup>` section? Note there are no line feeds in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID').clone().find("optgroup:first").remove().end().html();
```

Comment: This might a good idea but sorry I did not mention there are many optgroups. The one I need to remove is the first one. If it makes it easier I could give that one and id of 'admin'

Comment: @Anne adjusted the selector. You could also replace it with `.find(".js-admin-optgroup")` if you give that class to it. I.E. `<optgroup class="js-admin-optgroup">..</optgroup>`. The `:first` otherwise relies on the fact that the admin optgroup is always the first optgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to each optgroup and then use remove() function.

See example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ue2KJ/ .

If you like, you can avoid adding id to element, but if you will have more than one type of same element, then it may cause problems.

To remove first element just use -

```
$(this).children("optgroup:first").remove();
```